# Passing Parent Function to Child Component in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having my practice in VueJS 1.0 and I am learning about Components.
in this `example`, there is an `input` element and has to supply `coupon` or some kind of a `code` from an API. and I have to validate. I have my `<coupon >` component and has props of `when-applied`. The `when-applied` must call the parent function `setCoupon` but it won't.

I only got this error `this.whenApplied is not a function`.

```
    <div id="demo" class="list-group">
        <script id="coupon-template" type="x-template">
            <input type="text" v-model="coupon" v-on:blur="whenCouponHasBeenEntered">
            <div v-text="text"></div>
        </script>
      <coupon when-applied="setCoupon"></coupon>
    </div>
```

Here is my `app.js` file

```
Vue.component('coupon', {
  template: '#coupon-template',

  props: ['whenApplied'],

  data: function() {
    return {
      coupon: '',
      invalid: false,
      text: ''
    } 
  },


  methods: {
    whenCouponHasBeenEntered: function() {
      this.validate();
    },

    validate: function() {
      if( this.coupon == 'FOOBAR') {
        this.whenApplied(this.coupon);
        return this.text = '20% OFF!!';
      }

      return this.text = 'that coupon doesn`t exists';
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',

  methods: {
    setCoupon: function(coupon) {
      alert('set coupon'+ coupon);
    }
  }
});
```

Someone pls help. Suggestions pretty much appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should `bind` the property:

```
<coupon v-bind:when-applied="setCoupon"></coupon>
```

or you could use the shorthand syntax for `v-bind`:

```
<coupon :when-applied="setCoupon"></coupon>
```

Read more about the `props` [here](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Props).