# Call parent method with component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component and want to add a click listener that runs a method in the parent template in Vue. Is this possible?

```
<template>
    <custom-element @click="someMethod"></custom-element>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'template',
        methods: {
            someMethod: function() {
                console.log(true);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In the code you have posted, `someMethod` will be run when `custom-element` is clicked. Is that what you want or is there some other scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js inheritance call parent method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36764151/vue-js-inheritance-call-parent-method)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Directly from the Vue.js [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components):

> *In Vue, the parent-child component relationship can be summarized as props down, events up. The parent passes data down to the child via props, and the child sends messages to the parent via events...*

So you need to emit a `click` event from your child component when something happens, which can then be used to call a method in your parent template.

If you don't want to explicitly emit an event from the child (using `this.$emit('click')` from your child component), you can also try to use a [native click event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components), `@click.native="someMethod"`.

Answer (score 178):

**Yes!**

It's possible to call a parent method from a child and it's very easy.

Each Vue component define the property `$parent`. From this property you can then call any method that exist in the parent.

Here is a JSFiddle that does it : https://jsfiddle.net/50qt9ce3/1/

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<template id="child-template">
    <span @click="someMethod">Click me!</span>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <child></child>
</div>

<script>
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '#child-template',
  methods: {
    someMethod(){
        this.$parent.someMethod();
    }
    }
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  methods: {
    someMethod(){
        alert('parent');
    }
    }
});
</script>
```

**Note**: While it's not recommended to do this kind of thing when you are building disconnected reusable components, sometimes we are building related non-reusable component and in this case it's very handy.

Comment: this is no longer working for me, getting  this.$parent.myMethod is not a function

Comment: @raklos It still work with the latest version of vue.js which is 2.6.11 at the moment. If it's not working for you, the problem is elsewhere. I would suggest to ask another question with the code you are using for help.

Comment: @raklos chances are you are calling it in the "response section" of a function. In that case, the following question likely offers what you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51382072/vue2-call-parent-method-from-child-in-looped-component

Comment: For those who get the "this.$parent.myMethod is not a function" error try `this.$parent.$parent.myMethod` or `this.$parent.$parent.$parent.myMethod` and so on. It may happen that your method is not in the direct parent but somewhere higher in the components hierarchy.

Comment: This solution is highly unreliable because it relies on the components hierarchy. It'll not work if you call the method from different components inside a template:


`<template id="child-template">

    <!-- will work with this.$parent -->

    <span @click="someMethod">Click me!</span>

    <custom-component>

        <!-- will work with this.$parent.$parent -->

        <span @click="someMethod">Click me!</span>

    </custom-component>

</template>`

(sorry I can't manage to format the code properly here)

Comment: Using `$parent` is only for small static web sites, it isn't right solution for dynamic complex web sites as it is anti-pattern and will cause headache in the future. More chances to break the web site if e.g. a method in component moved to another component, you will have to update `$parent` everywhere and test the site again. Solution for this would be passing a method as a prop or using scoped slots.  

https://michaelnthiessen.com/pass-function-as-prop/

Comment: Provide/inject and props/emit are great tools for userland code, but when developing a library, you might not want to pollute your API by providing data to arbitrary descendants nor put the burdon on consumers to perform boilerplate event binding. A component communicating directly with its parent is only an antipattern when deployed in place of a more appropriate declarative idiom – sometimes code that smells bad will taste just fine. That said, $parent.$parent is a sinful temptation one must contemplate gravely before indulging.

Answer (score 38):

Relying on calling `this.$parent` hides the dependency and will break when you use component libraries which create a [longer child hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz4Hm.png)

#### The prefered methods are to either:

1. Explicitly **pass methods as properties** to child components (the same as passing data props)
2. Or **declare global methods as mixins**

#### From nils's answer on  [Vue.js inheritance call parent method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36765534/1366033):

1. **Passing props (parent-child)**

   ```js
   var SomeComponentA = Vue.extend({
       methods: {
           someFunction: function () {
               // ClassA some stuff
           }
       }
   });

   var SomeComponentB = Vue.extend({
      props: [ 'someFunctionParent' ],
      methods: {
          someFunction: function () {
              // Do your stuff
              this.someFunctionParent();
          }
      }
   });
   ```

   and in the template of SomeComponentA:

   ```html
   <some-component-b :someFunctionParent="someFunction"></some-component-b>
   ```
2. **Use Mixins**

   If this is common functionality that you want to use in other places, using a mixin might be more idiomatic:

   ```js
   var mixin = {
       methods: {
           someFunction: function() {
               // ...
           }
       }
   };
   var SomeComponentA = Vue.extend({
       mixins: [ mixin ],
       methods: {
       }
   });

   var SomeComponentB = Vue.extend({
      methods: {
          someFunctionExtended: function () {
              // Do your stuff
              this.someFunction();
          }
      }
   });
   ```

#### Further Reading

- [Vue.js - Making helper functions globally available to single-file components](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613061/1366033)
- [Vue Docs Mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

Comment: Number 1 is a great approach IMO. Best I've seen. I would have used Vuex for this but it would have been a lot of work to enable a modal.

Answer (score 8):

You can either pass the parent method down to the child component via `props` or you can get the child component to emit either a custom or native event.

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cKTFXl?p=preview) to demonstrate both approaches.

Answer (score 6):

In current vue version, this solution:
[Passing props (parent-child)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36765534/1366033)

```
var SomeComponentA = Vue.extend({
    methods: {
        someFunction: function () {
            // ClassA some stuff
        }
    }
});

var SomeComponentB = Vue.extend({
   props: [ 'someFunctionParent' ],
   methods: {
       someFunction: function () {
           // Do your stuff
           this.someFunctionParent();
       }
   }
});
```

The HTML part:

```
<some-component-b someFunctionParent="someFunction"></some-component-b>
```

Base on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391454/passing-parent-function-to-child-component-in-vuejs), should be modified in this way:

```
<some-component-b v-bind:someFunctionParent="someFunction"></some-component-b>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `$root` [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47110043/3377046) with vanilla Vue, but, If you use nuxt with vue that response won't work. Why? because `$root` is nuxt itself. Let me show you an example:

```js
this.$root.$children[1].myRootMethod()
```

- **`$root`:** As I said before, this is nuxt.
- **`$children[0]`:** this is nuxtloading.
- **`$children[1]`:** this is your main component, in my case, it was a basic layout with a few global components and a global mixin.
- **`$children[n]`:** other components on your app.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works but kind of anti-pattern. It decreases readability. For similar case(anti-pattern) and looking better one is just to accessing the $parent to call the method. `this.$parent.parentMethod()`

Comment: @ChaseChoi No, this doesn't work because my code is like an absolute path, it not depends on the children component because the result is always the same.

Comment: this.$parent.$options.methods.methodName();
Is the only thing that worked for me...

Comment: Yes, this could work if you only have a parent component not a great grandfather or an unknown ammount of parent components.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution for Vue 3:**

Another way to provide a function to a child component is to use provide/inject. The advantage is that you can avoid passing on props through multiple components, as inject can be used at any depth of child components.

Parent component:

```
<script setup>

import { provide } from 'vue'

myFunction(){
console.log('message from parent');
}

provide('message', myFunction);
```

Some child component:

```
<script setup>
import { inject } from 'vue'

const msg = inject('message')

//calling the injected function
msg()

</script>
```

Link to the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html).

Comment: How would this be implemented to use provide() and pass "someMethod" in the following example: export default { methods:{someMethod}}

Comment: On This link( https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html ) you can click on Options in the upper left corner to see examples for the Options API.