# Call Methods of Mixin within Component (Vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I can't call mixin method from the component, I get this error `this.hello is not a function`.

I can call `hello()` from Vue instance but I can't call it within the component.

What's a matter?!

```html
<div id='vue-app'>
  <cmp></cmp>
</div>
```

```js
const mixin = {
  methods: {
    hello() {
      return 'Hello World!';
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log('Mixin Created!');
  },
};

const cmp = {
  created() {
    console.log('From Cmp:', this.hello());
  },
};

new Vue({
  components: {
    cmp
  },
  el: '#vue-app',
  mixins: [mixin],
  created() {
    console.log('From VM:', this.hello());
  },
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ar464soq/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems I have to load the Mixin throughout of the Component instance, not from Vue parent instance :)

Comment: is there a way we just need to declare on vue parent, so we do need to redeclare it again in child component?

Answer (score 5):

Correct, mixin methods/data are only available with in the instance its added to. However if you really want the mixin in your root intstance you can call `this.$root.hello()` from any child component of the root instance

Answer (score 0):

If you use nuxt with vue @daxigu won't work because the `$root` is nuxt it self. What can I do? This:

```
this.$root.$children[1].myRootMethod()
```

- **$root:** As I said before, this is nuxt.
- **$children[0]:** is nuxtloading.
- **$children[1]:** is your main component, in my case, it was a base layout with a few global components and a global mixin.

Hope it helps.