# Vue2 call parent method from child in looped component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, event-bus

I'm looping root component, which have  with child component.

```
<root-select v-for="offer in offers"  >
   <child-options v-for="item in options" >
   </child-options>
</root-select>
```

But, when I  `$emit` root function from child, all my roots component changed those data.

child:

```
EventBus.$emit('toggle', value);
```

root:

```
EventBus.$on('toggle', this.toggle);
```

But I need, that data changes only in triggered component.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the this.toggle function do?

Comment: Why are you using an `EventBus` Instead of listening to the event on the component?

Comment: Karl-André Gagnon, you mean like this.$emit('toggle', value) ?

Comment: No, I mean like `<child-options v-for="item in options" @toggle="this.toggle(item)">` and you toggle function would look like `(item,value) -> item = value;`. Of course, I assume `toggle` do more than assign value, else `@toggle="item = $event.value"` would be enough.

Comment: It has been a while I didn't touch Vue, so it might not be exact, but the logic is here.

Comment: unfortunately it is not working in my case

Answer (score 5):

Try not to use Event bus to emit. Use normal Emit way to emit from child to parent.

In child component function:

```
this.$emit('toggle', value);
```

In parent component function:

```
<template><child-options v-for="item in options" @toggle="onToggleFn"></child-options></template>

<script>
...
methods:{
     onToggleFn:function(){
         //your logic here
     }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer is plain and simple to understand. Thank you.