# Vue: Wait until parent function is finished running

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am calling a parent function but my axios call after that is firing before the parent function finishes.  Is there  a way to use a Promise here  so that the parent function resolves first before my axios post call is made?

```
let data = {
   name: "Charles"
   age:  44
}

this.$parent.updateInfo(data);

axios.post('/admin/setup/change', {
    status: "new",
    comment: this.newNotes,
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `$parent.updateInfo` is asynchronous you can do something like that:

```js
this.$parent.updateInfo(data)
  .then(() => {
    axios.post('/admin/setup/change', {
      status: "new",
      comment: this.newNotes,
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.message);
  })
```

Then you can be sure that `axios.post` will be called after `$parent.updateInfo`

Comment: interesting...inside `updateInfo` is an axios call.  I can still use `then()` like that in the child?

Comment: `updateInfo` return Promise so you can use `.then` on this promise to handle the result of this promise. Read this it should help you to understand:
 - [What is promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
 - [handling promise with .then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

Comment: You can also use `await` which makes code more clear but then method in which you want to call this `await $parent.updateInfo` and `await axios.post` has to be asynchronous (`async`).
[async & await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Answer (score 1):

You can use async/await, so the code will wait until execute further.

Btw i don't think `this.$parent.updateInfo(data);` is the common approach to trigger a function from the parent scope. I would prefer to emit an event to the parent instance, as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46208765/11377556